# Write a ruby method that checks algorithm for checksum

Tags: ruby, methods, checksum

I'm creating a string using a K + 6 + 1 (prefix + code + checksum) format. I would like to write a method that checks my `label`and verifies that the checksum algorithm is correct. I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

```
require 'benchmark'

class Integer
    def to_bin(width)
        '%0*b' % [width, self]
    end
end

integer_number = 1
binary_number = integer_number.to_bin(24)
dictionary = '3467ACDEFGHJKMNP'
prefix = 'K'

code = ''
checksum = ''
label = ''

p '================ A1 ================'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report do
        parity = 0
        binary_number.scan(/\d{4}/).reverse.each_with_index do |item, index|
            word = item.to_i(2)
            parity = index == 0 ? word : parity ^ word
            code += dictionary[item.to_i(2)]
        end

        checksum = dictionary[parity]
        label = prefix + code + checksum
    end
end
```